# How to give permission to deploy to a spesific slot only?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have a Web App in Azure with deployment slots. Application is placed in ASE.
I need a service principal (App registration) in Azure AD that has permission to deploy to only a specific slot, not the whole Web App.

A service principal with "Contributor" role asignment was created for the TEST slot only. This service principal has no access to the whole web app, has no role there.

When deployment to the TEST slot the following error comes up:

```sh
az login --service-principal --username XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX --password ... --tenant XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX

az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group myresgroup --name mywebapp --src archive.zip --slot test

ERROR: AuthorizationFailed - The client 'XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX' with object id 'XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX' 
does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/sites/publishxml/action' 
over scope '/subscriptions/XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX/resourceGroups/myresgroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/mywebapp' 
or the scope is invalid. 
If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
```

Is it possible to give a permission for deployment to a specific slot only?

Comment: What happens if the `owner` role is granted to the service principal?

Comment: The same error with owner role in a slot: The client does not have authorization to perform action.

Comment: Even Reader role over Web App itself does not help to deploy to a slot. Only Contributor role in Web App allows to deploy to slots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to define a custom role with permission to only do `Microsoft.Web/sites/publishxml/Action`.

I called the role **Publishing profile reader**.

1. Create `Publishing profile reader` role at the Web App level.

`Publishing profile reader` role is copied from the `Contributor` role, here is JSON definition:

```json
{
    "properties": {
        "roleName": "Publishing profile reader",
        "description": "Role has permission to read website publishing profile.",
        "assignableScopes": [
            "/subscriptions/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx/resourceGroups/myresgroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/mywebapp"
        ],
        "permissions": [
            {
                "actions": [
                    "Microsoft.Web/sites/publishxml/Action"
                ],
                "notActions": [
                    "Microsoft.Authorization/*/Delete",
                    "Microsoft.Authorization/*/Write",
                    "Microsoft.Authorization/elevateAccess/Action",
                    "Microsoft.Blueprint/blueprintAssignments/write",
                    "Microsoft.Blueprint/blueprintAssignments/delete",
                    "Microsoft.Compute/galleries/share/action"
                ],
                "dataActions": [],
                "notDataActions": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

2. Then assign this custom `Publishing profile reader` role at main Web App to a service principal that is used for slot deployment.
3. Assign `Contributor` role to that service principal at slot level.

Thus this service principal can deploy at a slot, but has no permission for deployment to production.